# Primes and the Unit circle.

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, complex-analysis, prime-numbers

Consider the "prime spiral" $f(z) = \sqrt{z}\exp(2\pi i \sqrt{z})$, for integer $z$. It has been shown that the intersections of $f$ with some quadratic curves contain a significantly disproportionate number of primes. Let $P = \{\exp(2\pi i \sqrt{p}) \;:\ p \;prime \}$, the set of unitized prime spiral coordinates.

1) Is $P$ equal to the circle group or is it a proper subset? (note that $P$ is countable)

2) What is the complement of $P$ in the circle group?

3) Is the complement a group?

4) Is the circle group equal to the closure of $P$?

Comment: Don't you miss an $i$ in the $\exp$?

Comment: "Compliment" (with an "i") and "complement" (with an "e") are TWO DIFFERENT words that mean two different things.  I corrected the spelling.

Comment: As a complement to the above discussion, may I compliment you all on your orthography. You deserve complimentary drinks!

Comment: Please take another look at the question, I've corrected a mistake that changes its nature significantly.

Comment: Since the new set is a subset of the old, the answers to 1), 3), and essentially 2) stay the same; the only question whose answer can really change is 4), and that comes down to whether the square roots of primes are dense mod 1; I believe that can still be shown, though it becomes a little more complicated.

Comment: Can you think of a sequence of irrational numbers that converges modulo 1, non-trivially?

Comment: There are other options besides density and convergence; for instance, they could only lie in a subset of the unit interval, or e.g. on a Cantor set.

Answer (score 3):

1. As you note, $P$ is countable. The circle group (by which I take it you mean the set of complex numbers of modulus one) is uncountable. So, $P$ is a proper subset.
2. I don't think there's much you can say about the complement (note spelling), except that it's the complement.
3. No, the complement is not a group. Take any transcendental $\alpha$; then $e^{2\pi i\alpha}$ and $e^{2\pi i(1-\alpha)}$ are in the complement, but their product isn't.
4. Yes. It's well-known, and not hard to prove, that the numbers, fractional part of $\sqrt n$, are dense in the unit interval.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to Gerry's answer, another straightforward way of showing that $P$ can't be the circle group is to note that $P$ isn't even a group; there is no $n$ with $\sqrt{n}\equiv\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\pmod 1$.  For if there were, then there would be some $m$ with $\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+m$; but then $n=(2+3+m^2)+2m\sqrt{2}+2m\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{6}$ ; and $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ can be easily shown to be linearly independent over the integers.

Comment: Andrew's spelling seems to be contagious.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Auuugh.  Fixed!